# Не обновляется текст (replace() JS) после перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, текст

Пытаюсь автоматизировать задание маркетолога, и нужно сделать простенький скрипт для замены текста в документе.
Проблема заключается в том, что после перезагрузки страницы текст не обновляется, а остаётся прежним (Хоть он и изменился после запуска скрипта).
Сайт сторонний, не мой, пишу лишь скрипт для замены.

```js
function changeText() {
    let text = /Text/g;
    let replaceText = "Privet";
    document.getElementsByClassName("fr-element fr-view")[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByClassName("fr-element fr-view")[0].innerHTML.replace(text,replaceText);
    document.getElementById("article-create").click();
}
changeText();
```

Т.е после нажатия кнопки (На сайте это кнопка "SAVE"), по-идее должно произойти сохранение документа, но этого не происходит.
Дополнительная загвоздка вот какая:
1.Запуск скрипта и изменение текста
2.НАЖИМАЕМ на текст в div'е
3.Нажимаем на кнопку Save
4.Перезагружаем страницу
5.Profit

Но метод click/focus для div никаким образом не работает.

div:

```html
<div class="fr-element fr-view" dir="auto" contenteditable="true"
style="min-height: 50vh;" aria-disabled="false" spellcheck="false">

//Some text here//

</div>
```

Собственно есть два пути:
 - Сделать что-то с сохранением и перезагрузкой
 - Сделать нажатие на этот div (Ещё раз отмечу, что click() никаким образом не работает, когда нажимаю вручную на этот самый DIV, то сразу появляется курсор в том месте куда я нажал и появляется border этого div'a)

Comment: А как Вы себе представляете сохранение изменений после перезагрузки? Если Вы просто что-то меняете скриптом на стороне клиента, разумеется, ничего не может просто так сохраниться. Нужна либо база данных, либо localStorage на худой конец

Comment: Т.е проблема скорее на стороне сайта, в том что кнопка не сохраняет?
Я ведь говорю, сам по себе скрипт - он меняет (хоть и на клиентской стороне) текст, и нажимает на кнопку save, так же alert о сохранении появляется, но собственно сохранения не происходит.

Comment: Да нет, проблема в подходе. Нельзя сохранить изменения, сделанные скриптом на странице, без помощи какого-то хранилища (локального или базы данных).

Comment: что за кнопка `article-create` какой у нее обработчик?

Comment: если ты жмешь ее руками - текст сохраняется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При нажатии на поле ввода - будет происходить замена текста. 
При нажатии на кнопку данные будут сохраняться в `localstorage`.
Пример:

```js
    function changeText() {
        let text = /text/g;
        let replaceText = "Privet";
        let bz = document.getElementsByClassName("fr-element fr-view")[0];
        bz.onfocus = function () { //При нажатии на input заменяем текст
            bz.innerHTML = bz.innerHTML.replace(text,replaceText);
        }
    }
    changeText();

    var button = document.getElementById('article-create');
    button.addEventListener('click', function () { // При нажатии на текст сохраняем в хранилище
        let text = document.getElementsByClassName("fr-element fr-view")[0].innerHTML;
        localStorage.setItem('text', text);
    });

    let text = localStorage.getItem('text'); // Берём значение из localstorage

    if(text){ // Если значение не пустое
        document.getElementsByClassName("fr-element fr-view")[0].innerHTML = text; // То добавляем текст в поле.
    }
```

```html
<div class="fr-element fr-view" dir="auto" contenteditable="true"
     style="min-height: 50vh;" aria-disabled="false" spellcheck="false">

    //Some text here//

</div>
<button id="article-create">Тык</button>
```

Comment: Никак не могу разобраться, куда здесь поместить (Текст который нужно заменить) и (его замену)?

Comment: Подозреваю автор вопроса не имел ввиду сохранить локально, а скорее вызвать запрос соответствующий ручному нажатию на кнопку, при котором все работает.

Comment: @MarieSonner Объясните подробнее чего хотите добиться? Чтобы при нажатии на див, происходила замена текста, при нажатии на кнопку, или просто при загрузке происходила замена текста, а при нажатии на кнопку "SAVE" это просто сохранялось при перезагрузке?

Comment: @MarieSonner Добавил изменения.

Comment: @Denis640Kb Я хочу просто поставить курсор в этот самый див (Как пример в начало, середину, конец, куда угодно, лишь бы произошёл клик и появилась мигающая | ) при этом чтобы всё это выполнилось автоматически. Т.е я запускаю скрипт и всё, больше ничего делать не нужно, просто после запуска скрипта, курсор поставился сам, кнопка нажалась сама, текст заменился самостоятельно, без помощи рук.

Comment: @MarieSonner В примере это есть. При нажатии на этот див - выполняется функция `changeText()`. При нажатии на `SAVE` - текст сохраняется в `localstorage`

Comment: Отлично, благодарю за решение, всё работает!